# Checking two int arrays for equality - Regardless of order

Tags: java, arrays, equals

Disclaimer: This IS homework, so please don't just give me code, I'd like a sort of explanation of how I could go about doing this with as little actual code as possible.

So I have two integer arrays that are unsorted and equal length, and can contain duplicate values. As this is homework, there is the strange condition that I'm not allowed to use anything from java.utils or sort the array.

I'm supposed to check if the two arrays contain identical elements regardless of order. So comparing the arrays [5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 3] and [6, 6, 7, 5, 5, 3] would return true, while comparing [7,7 8] and  [7, 8, 8] would not.

I'm at a loss to how to do this, I've searched up questions but they all seem to use either something from java.utils, or the arrays do not contain duplicates. I've tried doing looping through each value in the first array, and for each value loop through the second array checking if that value exists there, but it trips up on duplicates.

I'd be greatful for any sort of help, advice, or tips in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any limitation to the range of numbers that can be contained in the array? Or are they just arbitrary `int`s?

Comment: It will be relatively short arrays, so no need to worry about performance. But yes, otherwise arbitrary int s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about taking each element from the first int array in turn, and checking to see if you find it in the second int array.  To make this idea work, you'll need to create an an array of boolean values which, are all initialised to `false`, to indicate whether a value in the second int array has been used or not.  Then when you find each value from the first array, set the corresponding element in the boolean array to `true`.

Comment: How would this account for checking if the number from the first array occurs the same number of times in both arrays?

Comment: For each element in the first int array, once it has changed a `false` to a `true` in the boolean array, it should not check any more values, and begin again on the next element in the int array. This way, the whole array will only be `true` if every element in the int array corresponds to a change in the boolean array.

Answer (score 3):

One way is iterate over the first array and to remove the elements that are equal as you find them in the second array.

When you fail to find an element from the first array in the second then the arrays were not equal. When you have found the last element from the first array in the second array then the arrays were equal.

If the arrays are not to be modified then you'll have to clone the one you change first.

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution, may get slow on longer arrays because it is O(n²)

```
// return how often n appears in an array
public static int count(int n, int[] array) { ... }

public static boolean equalarrays(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
   for (int i: arr1) {
       if (count(i, arr1) != count(i, arr2)) return false;
   }
   return arr1.length == arr2.length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
1   public static boolean compare(int[] a, int[] b)
2   {
3       if(a.length != b.length) return false;
4
5       aloop:for(int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
6       {
7           bloop:for(int j = 0; j < b.length; ++j)
8           {
9               if(a[i] == b[j])
10              {
11                  for(int k = j; k < i; ++k)
12                  {
13                      if(a[k] == b[j])    continue bloop;
14                  }
15
16                  continue aloop;
17              }
18          }
19
20          return false;
21      }
22
23      return true;
24  }
```

This basically says: take two arrays of same size *(3)* `a` and `b`, iterate trough `a` *(5)*, iterate trough `b` *(7)*, compare element of `a` to every element of `b` *(9)*, if any element of `b` equals element of `a`:

- If true: check whether this element of `a` was already processed iterating over index of a-loop *(11)* and comparing with already processed elements *(13)*.

  - If true: get next element of `b` and repeat. *(13)*
  - If false: get next element of `a` and repeat. *(17)*
- If false: well, when none element of `b` equals element of `a` return false *(18)*

If we got to the line *(23)* all elements of `b` are elements of `a`. Return true.

Edit: Additionally you may reverse aloop and bloop to get a bit of extra performance. (I haven't put it into the main code block as it tends to confuse people.)

```java
bloop:for(int j = 0; j < b.length; ++j)
// could be written as
bloop:for(int j = b.length; (--j) >= 0; )
// which is faster as the comparison and incrementation step are merged into one
```

Comment: It's certainly faster than Ingo's version as this doesn't necessarily compare every element of `a` to every element of `b` because of the `continue` skips. I'm unable to compare it with the accepted answer since I might not be able to think of the best implementation and the author doesn't mention sanity checks which are necessary for this approach. Literal implementation of the accepted answer would not return valid results.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fun activity I'll do on my own time. What I would suggest doing having two ArrayList's containing all the values of your two array tables. I'm doing this because you can use the `remove()` method. Loop through all the elements of the first array given. That is going to be your reference array. Get the object in the first iteration of your reference array. Then check if your other array(s)
have contain it. If it dosent then the check fails and you can return `false` right on the spot, if it does: remove it then get the next iteration of the reference array.

Even though you don't want the code, here it is in a pastebin: http://www.pastebin.com/3BEV2CqH
it accepts an `Object[] ... tables` argument and uses `equals` method to compare. I'm sure your teacher will be surprised if you can pull it off like I did.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to copy both arrays, then sort and compare the copies.  This is `O(NlogN)` if you use a good sort algorithm.  And you can write it in about 3 lines of code if you use the right library methods.

@Andy256 and @Stochastically's solutions should both work, but they are both `O(N^2)`.

Comment: But for some reason, the question says that the solution isn't allowed to use sorting.

Answer (score 0):

A common general-purpose approach is to sort the two arrays and then compare them.  This approach will always succeed in a predictable amount of time with any two arrays.  I don't think there's any algorithm whose worse-case time will be significantly better than the time required to sort the arrays.

In many cases, however, it may be useful to have a method which will "usually" be faster than sorting arrays.  As a simple example, suppose for each integer `X` one computes (X*(X+123456)), and adds together the totals of those values (as a `long`)  If two lists contain the same values, in any order, their sum should be equal.  It's possible that the lists might contain different values and yet still yield the same sum, but in most cases where lists contain different values, their sums could be recognized as different without having to go through the trouble of sorting the lists.

Another thing you might want to consider a "hash radix sort".  A radix sort works by having each pass divide things into buckets, then outputting the contents of the first bucket followed by those of the second, third, fourth, fifth.  Punched cards used to be sorted in this way, by using a machine which would examine one column on every card and dropping each card into one of thirteen buckets based upon what was punched there.  One could sort any number of 32-bit integers using one pass with 2^32 buckets, two passes with 65,536 buckets, four passes with 256 buckets, etc.  One slight annoyance with a radix sort, though, is that the distribution of things in the various buckets will often be substantially skewed.  If one defines a function which maps input values into e.g. numbers from 0 to 255 such that 1/256 of the inputs will be assigned each value, then one may in linear time reduce the task of "sorting" the list to that of sorting 256 lists, each of which is 1/256 the size.  Note that the resulting sequence won't be "sorted" in the conventional sense, but two lists containing the same items will get "sorted" the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. The post is old anyway

```
public static boolean equality(int[] list,int[] list2)
  {
    boolean result = false;
    int correct = 0;
    if(list.length == list2.length)
    {
      for(int i = 0; i< list.length; i++)
      {
        for(int j = 0; j < list2.length; j++)
        {
          if(list[i] == list2[j])
          {
            correct++;
            if(correct == list.length && correct == list2.length)
            {
              result = true;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```